# Graphs of diameter 2 chordless 7-cycle

Tags: graph-theory

If a chordless 7-cycle exists in a graph G with diameter 2 and $\Delta < n-1$. Then is there a $v \in V(G)$ such that N(v) contains at least tree vertices of 7-cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following counterexample. Start with the $7$-cycle $C_7$. Then, for any pair of non-adjacent vertices $u,v\in V(C_7)$, add a path of length $2$ between $u$ and $v$. The internal vertices of all these paths are assumed to be disjoint, so we get $14$ new vertices ($\frac{n\cdot (n-3)}{2}$). Between these new vertices, we connect every pair, so it becomes a clique. Now we have diameter $2$ and maximum degree $15$, whereas the number of vertices is $21$. The original cycle remains chordless, and each vertex has exactly two neighbours on it.

Comment: Actually, half of these new vertices are redundant, as they connect vertices that are already at distance $2$ from one another. So we can even make a counterexample with only $14$ vertices in total. Oh well.